# DropZone: How to Accept .csv Files?

Tags: dropzone, react-dropzone

I've read quite a few answers on SO about this, and most advise using the `acceptedFiles` property to specify the accepted mime types.

However, [the DropZone docs say](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#!/Dropzone):

> Mime type determination is not reliable across platforms. CSV files,
>   for example, are reported as text/plain under macOS but as
>   application/vnd.ms-excel under Windows. In some cases there might not
>   be a mime type set at all.

I'm trying to upload a .csv file, and (using `material-ui-dropzone`), so far I've tried:

```
  <Dropzone
    acceptedFiles={['.csv', 'text/*']}
    showPreviews={true}
    showFileNamesInPreview={true}
  />

  <Dropzone
    acceptedFiles={'.csv', 'text/*'}
    showPreviews={true}
    showFileNamesInPreview={true}
  />

  <Dropzone
    acceptedFiles={'.csv', 'text/csv'}
    showPreviews={true}
    showFileNamesInPreview={true}
  />
```

...etc., but so far none are working:

- The open file dialog shows `.csv` files as grayed out
- Dragging-and-dropping a `.csv` file to DropZone gets a "File SeriesNotes.csv was rejected. File type not supported." message

What is the correct way to solve this for `material-ui-dropzone` (or for any version of DropZone)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, this worked for me.

```
acceptedFiles={[".csv, text/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/csv, text/x-csv, application/x-csv, text/comma-separated-values, text/x-comma-separated-values"]}
```

The main one on windows was the .csv the rest are just in case.

Comment: this work wells, Noted that this's better to add 1-element array, like this answer used, instead of separate them differently in each array element

Comment: accept: "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel" --> this worked for me for csv and text files, but it also accepts .xls files, which I am trying to avoid. Any suggestions?
Edit: As far as I can tell, application/vnd.ms-excel is the accepting criteria for .csv & .xls files. The other params aren't really do anything. Could you please verify at your end if this is true as well? I'm having trouble with exclusions

Comment: : if I remove acceptapplication/vnd.ms-excel, it is correctly excluding .xls and .xlsx files, and accepting .csv files only. However, onHover, it shows up as an unaccepted file type. Sorry if I'm confusing you. Will find a solution and update it here

Comment: Thank you @user1767752 that worked out just fine to me!

Answer (score 0):

After more trial and error, got the following - csv only, no xls

React-Dropzone 12.1.0

```
  <Dropzone
    accept=".csv, text/csv, application/csv, text/x-csv, application/x-csv, text/comma-separated-values, text/x-comma-separated-values"
   >
```

what a nightmare!!